# Onchange in Struts2 textfield

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I want to get all records from DB to JSP based on a string what I enters in S2 textfiled. While typing in textfiled only I want to get those all records as a table in JSP.

**Ex:**

In textfiled, while I typing 'a' then I want to display all records which are matched with typing character 'a'. Suppose in my DB, I've some values with column 'name' as 'abc','def','bac','dea',etc. Then I want to get all the rows with column value 'abc','bac', and 'dea' from DB. **It's exacly like onchange event in HTML.** Here I can query like '**select name from tablename where name like%a%**'.

So in JSP,

```xml
   No     Name     Address
  -------------------------
   1      abc      addrs1
   2      bac      addr2
   3      dea      addr3
```

while I tried with

```xml
<s:textfield label="Search" name="keyword" id="keyword" onchange="search()"/>
```

It didn't work.

While I tried with

```xml
<s:textfield label="Search" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeypress="search()"/>
```

Its also exactly not working. Here onkeypress event mechanism working. After typing 'ab' only value 'a' will be send to action class. Ok. Is there any other way to do this.

```js
$.getJSON('/test/giveMeJsonData.action ',{cartId: cartId},function(json){
    itemsHtml = "<table>";
    for (i in json.items) {
        itemsHtml += "<tr>";
        itemsHtml += "<td>" + json.items[i].id + "</td>";
        itemsHtml += "<td>" + json.items[i].name + "</td>";
        itemsHtml += "<td>" + json.items[i].address + "</td>";
        itemsHtml += "</tr>";
    }
    itemsHtml += "</table>";
    $('#cartItems').html(itemsHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `onkeyup`, it will call JavaScript when key up is performed:

```xml
<s:textfield label="Search" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="search()"/>
```

[**JS Bin demo**](http://output.jsbin.com/lafivosodu/1)

---

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("searchText").value;
    alert(x);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchText" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

The widget you are talking about is called autocompleter (that is, guess what, a textfield with autocompletion fired by keyboard events).

You can easily achieve this with javascript widgets (eg. [jQuery autocompleter](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)), and in Struts2 you can also opt for the [struts2-jquery-plugin's Autompleter](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag).

In Action, return a List or an array:

```java
public String[] getMyList() {
    return myList;
}
```

In JSP, use it like this:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
  </head>
  <body>
   <sj:autocompleter list="%{myList}"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry my question is different. I know about autocompleter.

Comment: Not at all I think. With autocompleter if I type 'a', the word starting with letter 'a' will coming as suggection. But i want to get not only with starting letter also with middle or end of the word also. Is this possible with autocompleter.

Comment: @sowmyakonduru : sure it is! Check out the showcase: http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action  ( Widget -> autocompleter -> any one of the autocompleters). Try it by yourself ;)

Comment: @sowmyakonduru Be aware that you can upvote every question you like; as it is now, you've not even upvoted the one you've accepted...